# cucumber jvm CucumberException: No features found at []

Tags: cucumber, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-junit

In my cucumber -jvm, Maven, junit Setup I have my testRunner file as

```
package com.lebara.testrunner;

import cucumber.junit.Cucumber;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@Cucumber.Options(

glue = {"com.lebara.stepdefs","com.lebara.framework.main", "com.lebara.testrunner"},
features = "C:/Users/sarthak.dayanand/Documents/WebRefreshTest/CukeAutomation/LebaraWebAutomationTest1/src/main/resources",
format = {"pretty", "html:target/cucumber-html-report", "json-pretty:target/cucumber-report.json"},
tags = {"@UserJourney"}

)
public class RunCukesTest {
}
```

I have my feature file in the above mentioned directory.

If I run it, I get the following exception:

```
cucumber.runtime.CucumberException: No features found at [C:/Users/sarthak.dayanand/Documents/WebRefreshTest/CukeAutomation/LebaraWebAutomationTest1/src/main/resources/cucumber]...
```

If I remove the "features" option in the testrunner, it tries to look for feature files in the same directory as my testrunner.java

```
cucumber.runtime.CucumberException: No features found at [com/lebara/testrunner]
```

And if I put the feature files there, it works.

My question is why is my feature file not being picked up from my previous location, which I thought to be the default file structure for cucumber - maven setup.

How do I make it pick up from there? Help appreciated.

Answer (score 19):

Where exactly are your test runner and feature files?  I've got the following setup which works perfectly:

```
src/test/
    java/
        com/mypackage/
            TestRunner.java
            StepDefinition.java
    resources
        com/mypackage/
            fancy.feature
```

The Maven/Cuke conventions will have the tests executed from the tests/java directory and the feature files found in the test/resources directory.  My test runner is basically the same as yours but with less options:

```
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@Cucumber.Options(format = {"pretty"})
public class TestRunner { }
```

Hope this helps if you hadn't already found an answer.

Comment: changing from ".features" to ".feature" fixed it for me; thanks

Answer (score 6):

I have a setup similar to yours (not using the Maven/Cucumber conventions). In my options, I don't specify the path from root, but from the project's source folder where the features are held. It makes sense, since otherwise the tests would only be runnable from your machine.

In your case, I think it should be:

```
features = "src/main/resources"
```

Answer (score 3):

Just add features = { "classpath:features/feature.feature"}, and the feature must under **test/resources/features/feature.feature**.

```
    @CucumberOptions(
        format = {"pretty", "html:target/html"},
        features = {"classpath:features/feature.feature"},
        snippets = SnippetType.CAMELCASE
```

Note **classpath**.

When you compile your code if you are using maven open up **target/test-classes/features** and you will see **feature.feature**

Answer (score 3):

```
//Removing the space between "**classpath**" and "**:com/**" helped.

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        features = {"classpath:com/tk/feature/"}, //NOTE: NO SPACE
        glue = {"classpath: com.tk.cucumber"}, 
        plugin = {
                "pretty", 
                "html:build/reports/cucumber" 
                ,"json:build/reports/cucumber-tests/test.json"}
        )
public class RunAPITests {}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are providing the complete path of the feature file i.e.

"C:/Users/sarthak.dayanand/Documents/WebRefreshTest/CukeAutomation/LebaraWebAutomationTest1/src/main/resources" as in your query, try again by replacing the '/' character with '\\'(double back slash) as below.

"C:\\Users\\sarthak.dayanand\\Documents\\WebRefreshTest\\CukeAutomation\\LebaraWebAutomationTest1\\src\main\\resources\\abc.feature"

Answer (score 0):

This is a git repo which uses the latest cucumber version : [Cucumber- Example](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-java-skeleton)

Clone this repo and run it in your local machine. The `@Given` is defined and it should pass. The `@Then` and `@When` should be shown as undefined.

This is how the output for it should look :
[Output for the Belly feature](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pNmvB.png)

Use the structure mentioned : 
`src / test / java/ io /cucumber /` {Step definitions java and run cucumber test files here}
`src /test / resources/ io/ cucumber /` {feature files here}

You can run the gradle build using `./gradlew clean build`
and the cucumber test using `./gradlew clean test --info`

If this works, then use the same format in your project.

Answer (score 0):

Just changing **.F**eature to **.f**eature the problem got resolved for me.

Also make sure the path for feature is righly mention in **CucumberOptions** as per your feature folder

Some of the online tutorial have mentioned .**F**eature which brings this problem

so changing the case will solve this problem

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is another instance in which 'Feature Not Found' error occurs. I am posting the solution under this answer as there is no similar question.

I got this error when trying to run the Runner file first time after setting up Cucumber project in Maven. The solution i found was as follows: Go to the folder in which the 'feature' file is present in Windows Explorer. Check the size of the feature file you are trying to run. If the size is '0' KB, it will show the 'Feature Not Found' error. Make some changes to file until a value greater than zero is displayed. Run again after making changes.

Comment: I have same error with feature file size as non-zero.

Answer (score 0):

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
    features = {"src/main/resources/cucumber/features"},//your feature path
    tags = "not @Wip",
    glue = {"classpath:steps"},
    plugin = {"pretty", "html:target/cucumber/html"})
```

You must set the feature directory correctly

Answer (score 0):

Right click on your runner file and select runAs then click on run-configuration. From there, go to your feature file—as shown in the image—and configure your feature path there. Finally, run again. It should solve your problem.

[image]

Answer (score -4):

By putting the feature file under **src/test/java** where the runner and steps file or
by putting it under **src/main/java** the problem will get resolved.

Comment: Don't put test code under **src/main**. That folder generally contains code that goes to production and you don't want test code going to production.